# I want to send the meeting invite on outlook using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, html

I have a scenario where i want to send a meeting invite to specific person in outlook using angularjs. Please, provide the required codes or link to do so.

Comment: You need to call rest API which is i guess provided by microsoft. this might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39912401/outlook-rest-calling-form-angularjs

Comment: I am getting the code but can you explain what is $scope.token there .

Comment: token require to communicate to rest api like Oauth or some api in which required to authenticate

Comment: I am new to rest so can you tell what exactly the token here referred.

Comment: you can find access token guide at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/get-started

Comment: https://imageshack.com/a/img922/1706/vMAN9t.jpg